# Merge two arrays in same row JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an issue where I can't merge two arrays in same row, I have two arrays now , then I want to combine them since they have the same length

this is my two array looks like

[image]

and I want Output like this by combining this but this is what I tried by

[image]

```
const ar1 = $('input[class=namecheckbox]').map((i, el) => ({id: el.id.slice(2)})).get();
const ar2 = $('.quantity_input').map((i, el) => ({quantity: el.value})).get();

const merge= $('input[class=namecheckbox]').map((i, el) => ({id: el.id.slice(2),quantity: el.value})).get();

console.log(ar1);
console.log(ar2);
console.log(merge);
```

Can anyone know how to solve my problem? thanks in advance

Comment: map one array and use the index to access the other array

Comment: `const merge= $('input[class=namecheckbox]').map((i, el) => ({id: el.id.slice(2),quantity: $('.quantity_input')[i].value})).get()`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting wrong value due to this,
**const merge= $('input[class=namecheckbox]')...** Because ar2 getting data from this selection, **$('.quantity_input')...**

This also work,

```
var merge = [];
for(var i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++){
  let obj = {id: ar1[i]['id'], quantity: ar2[i]['quantity']};
  merge.push(obj);
}
```